# How to reopen this question?

Tags: support, status-declined, specific-question

I would like to just contact the moderator who closed [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/63465/how-do-you-edit-a-srt-subtitles) but I don't know how, so I'm posting here.

The moderator is saying that this question is a duplicate, but I specifically am asking users how to hard code subtitles into a video.  The other one is only asking how to sync the files, and just happened to receive answers that are similar to my asked question about editing.  But still, there is no answer on how to hard code the subtitles.

I suggest this gets reopened, if you disagree please tell me why, but I think this question is useful and people who have a similar problem can now easily find my question with answers.  As opposed to finding the wrong question with the right answer.

Comment: Though Diago will read your post here, you can also directly mail to `team@superuser.com` (see the "contact us" link at the bottom of every SU page).

Answer (score 5):

**I** am the moderator that closed the post and it will remain closed since the question was which software to use. The second part of the question should be posted as a **new** question since no one answering is even trying to answer the second part of the question, and the answers are the same as in the listed duplicate.

The post is now locked. This means there can be no further edits or changes to the post until it is unlocked. I would recommend you ask the second part of the question as a new question which will give you much better results.

Some notes.

- It clearly states in the closed by reason who closed it with a link to my profile.
- As already mentioned, please don't rollback duplicates, flag for moderator attention.
- You only need to flag for moderator attention once.

Comment: I'll delete the question and rephrase, but when I went to your profile there wasn't a way for me to contact you (internally, could have gone to your private website i guess), so I had to post here.

Comment: oh, I can't delete it...

Answer (score 4):

I hope you noticed that the *answers* you were getting are essentially the same as those on the original question. You may have had a different goal in mind, but because of the way you asked it folks were just answering by recommending subtitle editors.

You *probably* want to ask for specific directions for *a specific editor*...

**BTW:** it's rude to edit out the duplicate link when your post is still closed as a duplicate. All you're doing is making it harder for folks to find the question they can still answer...

Comment: no, actually one of the answers did have an answer to the hard coding.  One of them had the same program in the answer, and one of the others was pretty much an exact response.  So out of the 4 answers, practically three of them were different.  Anyway, I'm going to repost the question differently.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things

1. do what you did and post here
2. flag the question for moderator attention and explain your case
3. although this doesn't apply for you just yet, those with 3K+ rep can vote to reopen

Comment: thanks, i flagged it.  Is it supposed to show you that you've flagged it?  Because I'm able to flag it again apparently...

Comment: No, you won't see the flag after you've done it.